error in typescript while importing the p-retry library
I have found a lot of similar posts, but, I've not found one specifically for this scenerio (for p-retry) where, the library does provide it's own type-definitions, and has sample documentations doing the same, is updated to the latest version, yet when I import it:
import pRetry from 'p-retry';

it gives me the following error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /homeapi/node_modules/p-retry/index.js from /homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js:16:19) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}  

I don't exactly get what the error says entirely, however, I tried using dynamic modules:
const pRetry = import('p-retry'); // returns promise
// wherever I use pRetry, I do:
(await pRetry).default(....)

and it gives the same with additional exception trace:
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);  

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /homeapi/node_modules/p-retry/index.js from /homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js not supported.
    Instead change the require of index.js in /homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/homeapi/dist/mail/mailBase.client.js:16:19) {
      code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

If possible I would like to avoid dynamic modules. Is there something I'm missing in configuring things in some config files?
I'm using Nestjs (v9, latest), with typescript and node lts version (20.15.1 LTS). Any similar alternative npm-package suggestions would also be of great help.

This question is similar to: Unable to import ESM module in Nestjs. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Who needs a library to retry async operations anyhow? LOL. This code snippet is likely all you need ;)

this is just because you're using an ESM-only package in a CommonJS project, not related with nestjs itself
duplicate of Unable to import ESM module in Nestjs
and several others

await import().default ... actually didn't quite work for me
